# C# InvokeRequired with property getter

Tags: c#, invokerequired

I would like to make my getter thread safe. When I do this, I get an error:

```
public ApplicationViewModel SelectedApplication
    {
        get
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke((Action<ApplicationViewModel>)SelectedApplication);
            }

            return _applicationsCombobox.SelectedItem as ApplicationViewModel;
        }
    }
```

I have the error:

```
Cannot cast expression of type 'Foo.Model.ApplicationViewModel' to type 'Action<ApplicationViewModel>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of things wrong:

- you cannot use BeginInvoke, **`Invoke`** is required
- you cannot use Action<>, you are returning a value so **`Func<>`** is required
- you cannot also run the original code after invoking, **`else`** is required.

Which produces:

```
public ApplicationViewModel SelectedApplication
{
    get
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            return (ApplicationViewModel)this.Invoke(new Func<ApplicationViewModel>(() => this.SelectedApplication));
        else
            return _applicationsCombobox.SelectedItem as ApplicationViewModel;
    }
}
```

Hiding the thread context switches in a low-level property is usually a mistake.  Invoking has lots of overhead, the resulting code may end up being very slow without a good hint of why it is so slow.

Comment: Except it's transparent to the consumer; no other method has to care how it was invoked in order to get this property in a synchronous fashion. You'd only be able to reduce the slowdown in cases where you were 100% sure the caller was on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

`BeginInvoke` takes a delegate.

You can write

```
return (ApplicationViewModel)Invoke(new Func<object>(() => applicationsCombobox.SelectedItem));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public ApplicationViewModel SelectedApplication
    {
        get
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(() => { return SelectedApplication(); });
            }

            return _applicationsCombobox.SelectedItem as ApplicationViewModel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but now it says: "Method, event or delegate is expected" on the method SelectedApplication();